# REST API post times out when content is too large

Tags: rest-api

On my production Wordpress site, when I try to post via the REST API and the post is over 852 characters, I get `Error: socket hang up`. If it's 852 characters or less, it posts.

This only happens when I post from my Meteor Cloud Server.  I don't have this issue posting from my local machine.  I also pulled the production site to a staging server and do not have this issue.  So it only comes up when posting from my Meteor Cloud Server to the Production Wordpress Site

I tried:

- created .user.ini and added post_max_size = 64M
- Whitelisted IPs on Wordfence
- Turned off plugins
- Updated Theme
- Godaddy - no issue they can see

Comment: Is the post request from your local machine exactly the same as the post from the Meteor server? Does your request from the server send data in the request body or in the URL?

Comment: To @JacobPeattie's point, compare the requests coming from the different endpoints, especially the HTTP headers for each request to see if there are any differences. If not present in the header, you may need to add the ```Content-Length``` parameter.

Comment: I'm using wpapi to create the requests, here's my modified call setting the Content-Length and stringifying the values: 

`const result = await wp.posts().setHeaders({
'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
'Content-Length': JSON.stringify(postValues).length})
.create(JSON.stringify(postValues));`

Now my request is limited to 956 characters...

Comment: @JacobPeattie Exact same code running from my local and pushed to production.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for the suggestion!  It was an issue with wpapi so I ended up hitting the endpoint using fetch instead and it works!